# What is a "tar shower?"

Tags: meteorology, earthquakes, earth-history

I'm reading about Sodom and Gomorrah on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodom_and_Gomorrah#Historicity) when I come across this:
"One such idea is that the Dead Sea was devastated by an earthquake between 2100 and 1900 BCE. This might have unleashed showers of steaming tar."

What is a "tar shower?"  Are there any documented cases of this?  When I googled this, it went to the visual dictionary referenced in the Wikipedia article, which didn't explain the concept either.

Comment: This question has been cross posted on [SE History] (https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/42595/what-is-a-tar-shower)

Answer (score 1):

Natural oil seeps are not unusual, the light components evaporate leaving "tar". Then an earthquake could cause a release of gas which if in just the right location could blow the tar into the air.  Normally the gas escapes through the tar and throws it only a very shot distance, like an inch.